# Pronunciation of gunwale

Tags: pronunciation

I was watching an episode from 2007 of the Science Channel's [*How It's Made*](https://www.sciencechannel.com/tv-shows/how-its-made/) in which a [canoe was being constructed](https://www.sciencechannel.com/tv-shows/how-its-made/full-episodes/individual-transporters-cedar-canoes-electric-guitars)*.

The narrator consistently pronounced "gunwale" as `/ˈɡʌnheɪl/` (gunhale) with an aspirated "h" (and no "w"). I'm only familiar with the pronunciation `/ˈɡʌnəl/` (gunnel) and that (or similar) is the only pronunciation given in a few dictionaries I consulted.

Is there a dialect of English (or regional accent) in which his pronunciation is common?

`*` <sub>Sign in required to view video.</sub>

Comment: Why? I know how it's pronounced generally as I indicated in the question.

Comment: Are you aware that that word was spelled *gunwhale* during the 1800s, and that some folks pronounce such spellings with [ʍ]?

Comment: I don't know anything, but 'How It's made' is produced in Quebec, so it may be a Canadian English thing.

Comment: @tchrist: I thought I had seen that spelling before and I'm familiar with [ʍ], but the narrator was clearly saying [h] and not [ʍ].

Comment: Maybe somebody told the narrator "you don't pronounce the *'w'* in *gunwhale*" so he started pronouncing it *gunhale* instead.

Comment: This pronunciation *might* be common somewhere, but I will say it would still be wrong.  The only people who I've ever heard say it any way but "gunnel" were all landlubbers.

Comment: I've always heard it pronounced "gunnels", as in the Scots expression "fu' to the gunnels"...

Answer (score 1):

Anyone spend time on boats in Ireland? It seems many dialects there appreciate the aspirated h where other dialects use none.

Alternatively (having heard many flavors of mispronunciation of nautical terms) might it be the result of grappling with an unfamiliar word and finding a pronunciation that felt adequate?

Answer (score -1):

It's more like "gunnel". Like someone said, the Brits shorten "forecastle" to "fo'scle" and "boatswain" to "bosun" so "gunnel" would follow that trend. Some writers even use the spelling "gunnel" as a variant of "gunwhale" but this is not standard usage. (see Liz Dexter's website: she has a degree in English Language and Literature and is an editor, a qualified librarian and a published author so she would know.)

Comment: The OP is familiar with the “gunnel” (/ˈɡʌnəl/) pronunciation. The question is: Is there a dialect of English (or regional accent) in which his pronunciation (“gunhale”, or /ˈɡʌnheɪl/) is common? This is not an answer to the question.